# Date difference between two records in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (`job_logs`) with the following records:
`id`, `job_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `created_at`, `job_type`.

Each time a job starts to run a record is written in the `job_log` table with `status='started'`. When a job finish running another record is added to the table with `status='completed'`.

Both records has the same `user_id`, `job_type` and **job_id** (which is determined by the process running the job - unique to these 2 records).

I want a query that will return all these records pairs in the table (ordered by id desc) but the tricky part is that I want to add to the record with the 'completed' status the time it took the job to run (`completed.created_at - started.created_at`).

How can I do that?

Comment: Cant think of a way to do this without cursors. Will be interesting to see some ideas.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi, you don't have to use a cursor.  The wrost is to use a subquery on every job_id to find the matching "completed" record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT j1.job_id AS job_id, (j2.created_at - j1.created_at) AS time_run
FROM job_logs j1 INNER JOIN job_logs j2 ON (j1.job_id = j2.job_id)
WHERE j1.status = 'started' AND j2.status = 'completed'
```

Comment: Nice! :) Didnt even think of that.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi, this is a good trick that has served me well over the years.  You can basically use it to get results between any two rows in a table.  Self-joins are very useful in cases like this.  However, be careful of performance though -- self-joins can get large very quickly.

Comment: I`m so rusty on my sql it`s not even funny. I havn`t had a challenging query in a decade :) @Stephen Chung, I`m sure this can go cartesian product on you in a hartbeat.