# Querydsl for innerJoin of same table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpql, querydsl

SQL solution for this link is very interesting..
[Date difference between two records in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449496/date-difference-between-two-records-in-same-table#)

Can anybody help me to construct Querydsl for same query..??

```
JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(XXXXX)
```

Lets assume we havehas

```
QJobLogBean qjb = QJobLogBean.jobLogBean;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two from arguments

```
QJobLogBean qjb1 = new QJobLogBean("qjb1");
QJobLogBean qjb2 = new QJobLogBean("qjb2");
JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(qjb1, qjb2)...
```

Comment: I tried this inner join of same table, but unfortunately it doesnt give me desired output.

Comment: What exactly did you try and how did the SQL look like?